# .MP4 video (h.264 format) is not playing in iPhone when I host the video in Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, amazon-ec2, h.264

I have converted my `source.flv` video into `target.mp4` (h.264 format) by using following command:

```
ffmpeg -i source.flv -r 25 -b:a 128k -strict -2 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -s 320x240 -b:v 768k -ar 44100 -c:a aac target.mp4;
```

The `target.mp4` video is playing in my computer browser's but it's not playing on the iPhone / iPad when I host my video on an Amazon EC2 instance.

The same `target.mp4` video is playing in my computer browser's as well as the iPhone / iPad when I host it some place else.

QuickTime shows the following error when I try opening the video from the EC2 instance:

```
QuickTime
BYTE_RANGE_ERROR_MESSAGE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally we got the actual solution for 'Why our mp4(h.264)' videos are not playing in iphone .
**The solution is :** remove or comment compress.conf file from httpd.conf(apache server config file).

Compress.conf file is used to compress output before send it to client , If you don't want to remove compress.conf than you may comment few lines inside compress.conf. Comment

# Load the filter module

SetEnv filter-errordocs true

FilterDeclare comp-resp

# Compress everything except for images, audio and video

#FilterProvider comp-resp DEFLATE resp=Content-Type !/^(image|audio|video)//

#FilterProtocol comp-resp change=yes

Answer (score 2):

In order to stream video to these QuickTime / Apple devices, the server sends out an `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header. This indicates to the player that it can request certain parts of the video by sending a byte offset, which allows you to, for instance, begin streaming from the middle of a video without having to download the entire file.

Usually this works by default. However, byte range requests can also be considered a security risk, for example when a Denial of Service attack is launched against the server. For this reason, byte range requests may be blocked along the way, either through a router or firewall, or by the EC2 server itself, which would lead to the error message you're seeing.

Therefore, check the connection for possible blocked requests, or consider contacting EC2 support.

See also:

- [IIS7 Serving .mp4s, not playable on iOS devices](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15682/iis7-serving-mp4s-not-playable-on-ios-devices)
- [H.264 encoded MP4 presented in HTML5 plays on Safari but not iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240915/h-264-encoded-mp4-presented-in-html5-plays-on-safari-but-not-ios-devices)
- [BYTE_RANGE_ERROR_MESSAGE while...: Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12320329?messageID=12320329#12320329?messageID=12320329)

Comment: i have contacted Amazon development support and waiting for their reply.
Until their reply come, i am also doing some google search and found "qt-faststart".
Is it useful in my case(i,e progressive downloading in iPhone/iPad) ??

Comment: While not entirely related to your issues, using `qt-faststart` to move the `moov` atom to the beginning of your MP4 files is definitely encouraged for all kinds of streaming. See: [Understanding the MPEG-4 movie atom | Adobe Developer Connection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/articles/mp4_movie_atom.html)

Comment: The following are the headers from EC2 instance that we observed through liveheaders in firefox. 

[GET /tmp/race.mp4 HTTP/1.1 Host: xxx.com User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Connection: keep-alive ]

[HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)  Etag: "1e15b2-4cf6375252c50" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 1971634 Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: video/mp4]

Comment: And also not getting comprehensive reply from amazon support team , i am working with amazon support to get the appropriate solution

Comment: Well, that merely tells you that the server will allow `Accept-Ranges: bytes`, so yeah, it must be blocked along the way.